# Is it OK to contact a company asking for the closing date of a position?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, job-change, applications, email

## Main Question

I am looking at a job opening that has been open for a number of weeks. There is no closing date listed on any of this company's job listings. Is it OK to contact such a company and ask them how long the job opening will be available for?

In addition, is it likely such a company might be able to tie this back to my application? Would this potentially penalize me?

## Background

In the middle of March, I saw a job opening at one of my dream companies that I would love to do. This company usuallly has openings for senior positions in the role in question, so the mid level role was completely unexpected. However, given it involves moving half way across the country, and I was happy in the job I was, I decided not to apply, but have kept the tab open.

Fast forward a month and I have been promoted at my current job. Despite telling me the salary range for my previous role, and pointing out that I was at the very bottom end of it, the salary increase with the promotion was insulting at best, and almost certainly puts me below the normal salary range for my new position.

I have now decided to apply to the job opening I found, but I have made the mistake of not keeping my CV/information up to date during the almost 6 years in my current job (which was my first after graduating), and I am currently struggling while updating it. Knowing the closing date of the position is more than, for example, a week from now, would mean I don't have to rush updating it, and therefore potentially make mistakes.

The avenues I can contact the company in question are via a careers@companynamehere.com e-mail address or their @companynamehereCareers twitter account.

If it helps in any way, these are softward development jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it OK to contact a company asking for the closing date of a
>   position?

I don't see *anything wrong with inquiring* about that information.  However keep in mind the following:

1. Many companies, *especially big ones*, will post a position on a site and leave it there for months.
2. Many companies will only respond to candidates they are interested in.  Do not be hurt if your request for information goes un-answered.
3. Some companies will even post positions before the budget for said position is approved.  Meaning they believe they will get the money for it and then do not, but do not care to remove the job posting.

If your interested in making these inquiries anonymously, I would suggest a phone  call if you have a contact number.

Comment: Point number 4 should be: Positions close because they are filled or no longer needed.  Dates are therefore meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Showing interest in a position should never be a bad idea. And if you have questions about this offer, you should ask them.

Maybe it is the false way to ask "Is the offer long time open, because I need time to make a CV"  : ) But you can ask questions like "When should applicants have to start in this position?" And if they want to know your reasons you can talk about the time afford for relocation.

Another positive thing in this: you get in contact with the company, and away of this offer, maybe they are interested in you and your experience. You can see it like an application on your own initiative, so it is not bound to the time the offer will be open. For your "dream company" this should be an appropriate afford I think.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for a closing date make sure you follow these rules

- Don't wait till last minute
- Make it urgent, don't take your time even if the deadline is in the future
- Use an anonymous/new account to contact them

Focus on your CV, put lots of time and effort into it. You are completely right in leaving your current job if they openly told you that you were at the bottom end of your pay scale it clearly shows they don't value your skills and efforts.

As ThiefMaster said in the comments - It is very possible that they don't have an official closing date and they are just looking until they find the right person, but it's best to be sure right?